# Is there a way to use different network connections for different apps

Tags: wifi, firewall, network

At work we have a firewall that prevents certain outbound connections. But I also have a Clear wireless personal hotspot.  I would like to use the work connection for normal requests but for certain requests such as my Mysql app, I would like to use my personal wireless.  Is there a way to do that without having to switch back and forth.  So all mysql connections just know to use one network interface while other requests use the default.

Comment: You should take a look at [How can I restrict Mac sharing services to a specific network/adapter?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/960/how-can-i-restrict-mac-sharing-services-to-a-specific-network-adapter) (which this is probably a dupe of).

Comment: @Dori I think that's a different question -- that question was about restricting incoming connections, this is about routing outgoing connections.

Comment: @Gordon - If I thought it was an exact dupe, I would have just merged them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've asked the same question a long time ago on superuser.com

https://superuser.com/questions/181882/force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-interface

Comment: Adjusting the routing tables doesn't work by application, it works by remote IP address. So you have to know all the IP addresses that App 'A' needs (not always easy, esp. with different DNS on each interface), set up manual routes to those IPs, and then hope that App 'B' doesn't need any of those IPs also.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look in to routing with iptables.  I can't remember how off the top of my head, but it would definitely be possible to just catch packets going to a certain host/port and push them off through another interface.

Answer (score 1):

To separate traffic by *app* (and not by *destination*) would require an OSX version of something like [ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) (for Windows only). No matter how you change the routing tables or ipfw, if you have 2 apps that are trying to reach google.com, they will use the same interface, same route.

You might be able to approximate the same kind of behaviour by running each app in a chroot jail that can see only a limited set of devices, and restrict it to a single interface. But that would take a whole lotta configuation for each app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this using IPTables, but I'm not an expert at that so I can't really give you detailed information. However, that may point you in the right direction.

Essentially you would set a route for all outgoing connections on the port you connect to with mysql to use that wireless connection.

Comment: Not iptables, ipfw. Iptables is for linux. Same idea though everything packet related can be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely possible, but like the other people here, I don't know how to do it. Just that it certainly *can* be done.

Try asking in https://unix.stackexchange.com/.