# Prevent Bonjour Announcements Over OpenVPN

Tags: network, vpn, bonjour

We have an OpenVPN server at work, which I use frequently to access private work resources. When I do, the "Shared" listed in Finder populates with all the automatically announced servers/resources at work, but the reverse is also true. My local resources appear to anyone at work, and/or on the VPN as well.

Ideally, I would like to prevent my announcements from going over the VPN link, but would like to have the shares physically at work available to me while on the VPN. If the only method is to disable Bonjour (temporarily), I'll be fine with that, but is there a way to make it only one-sided?

And of course the master question: How do I accomplish this, at all, in the first place.

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/960/how-can-i-restrict-mac-sharing-services-to-a-specific-network-adapter

Comment: The sheer amount of Google Search results that link me back here now is astounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Bonjour only works on the local network and only its extension Wide-Area-Bonjour works through VPNs. Did you configure your Computer to use that or did you setup your router to handle that? Also, which other resources appear for the others at work?

But anyway, you don´t have to have File Sharing "turned on" on your computer (which will then cause the broadcasting of your computer´s name over Bonjour) to access others, so just turn off the services you don´t want others to see and you should be good.

Comment: (1) Bonjour doesn't work over PPTP/L2TP/etc. VPNs. I do not know the technical reason, but it does work over SSL VPNs and OpenVPN. I don't use ShareTool, and I don't have any special configuration to create this scenario. I see all my co-workers shares too, as a matter of fact. (2) Your suggestion is not a solution because it breaks functionality I use. *I* want to see the iMac upstairs (which isn't mine, btw), on my laptop I'm now typing on. I *don't* want individuals at work to be able to do the same.

Comment: (2): you didn´t specify what local resources you have; so without knowing of your local Macs my suggestion wouldn´t be that bad.

Comment: (1): Bonjour is a multicast protocol and does only work link local (so only in your local broadcast domain, not across subnets!) unless you use its "wide area" implementation; for that the DNS server you are using at work has to update all connected clients over dns-sd to publish its registered services. So the question would be why your iMac upstairs is registering itself at your work´s DNS-server once you start your VPN on your laptop?! Have you maybe entered your work´s DNS server in your router?

Comment: Could you describe which steps you had to take to get your vpn setup running? Did you simply have to import a openvpn.ovpn file or did you need to setup anything else, maybe with a .pkg installer you got from somebody at work?
Also, do you have an entry in your firewall to forward multicast packages to your work´s dns server? You could do "sudo ipfw list" in the Terminal and look for entries that forward 224.0.0.251 (that´s the mDNS area)

Comment: It looks like this problem was actually due to software actively relaying things. Namely: iTunes was actively relaying the existence of an AppleTV across the VPN. I think. Regardless, with a standard set of apps, nothing is exposed from my computer outside of my computer itself. Thanks for sticking around with me on this.

Answer (score 1):

How about blocking udp traffic on port 5353?

Comment: Is it actually that simple? Can I just filter outgoing 5353?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpenVPN, I assume you are using Linux on the server side.

Since OpenVPN is working in layer 2 bridge mode, applying a standard filter with `iptables` will not work. `iptables` works on layer 3 and your VPN is before that in the layer 2.

The trick is to use `ebtables` wich is like `iptables` but at layer 2.

You can block UDP port 5353 with `ebtables`.

Comment: Strange assumption since OpenVPN is cross platform, even though you are correct :P.